# Jquery easy variables issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass the variables to callback function in Jquery

I have:

```
var test;

$('.img').hover(function(){
   test='this is test';

}, function (){
   //how do I pass the test value to the callback function..??
   console.log(test)

})
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried running this code?

Comment: Demo: (Works fine) http://jsfiddle.net/UsMHW/ hope its fits your need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass it, you could access `test` in the second callback function.

Comment: ... since the variable belongs to the outer scope. Of course, there's a single variable shared among all elements with `img` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
var test;
$('.img').on('hover', function(){
test ='this is a test';
console.log(test);
});
```